# IB Instantiated UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Yes, I have set the contentsize. When I do an NSLog of the contentsize I get a height of 0 and a width of 0 which is a little confounding. It seems like my scrollview doesn't actually exist.

I think I'm setting up the scrollview wrong.

In IB I have a viewcontroller subclass that has a scrollview, inside the scrollview are other labels/views/etc.

Does the scrollview need to have a single subview that manages the "actual" subviews or something?

When I run an NSLog on the scrollview it comes up with this:

```
Scrollview: <UIScrollView: 0x81b2960; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x81b2dc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x81b7390>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: What happens when you do a NSLog of the scrollview?

Comment: Edited to give that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, I needed to have the contentsize code in a viewDidAppear method not in a viewDidLoad method. It's weird because the other changes were being made, just not this one. Go figure

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view does *not* need to have a single master subview.  I'd bet dollars to donuts you have forgotten to hook up the IBOutlet that should point to your UIScrollView in the xib file.

Comment: okay, I've checked it, it appears to be connected up. The NSLog of the object itself appears to return instantiated memory, but does not have a frame which is bizarre to me